# In quantum teleportation when exactly the original EPR pair stops being entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation, epr-experiment

In quantum teleportation Alice and Bob share a pair of entangled particles (EPR pair made of particles 2 and 3, for example). Alice has another particle (1) whose quantum state she wants to send to Bob. She inputs into a CNOT quantum gate her particle (1) in the control port and her side of the EPR pair (2) in the target port. She then make her particle (1) go through an Hadamard gate. Finally she measures the spin of both particles in the standard basis. The two bits that she measures are send to Bob via a classical channel.
My question is: At what instant do the two particles of the EPR pair (2 and 3) stop being entangled and Alices original particle (1) becomes entangled with her part of the EPR pair (2)? Is it just after the CNOT gate? Or is it when she makes the measurements on her two particles?

Comment: when they are measured. Local operations on either side cannot affect the entanglement.